# Nhibernate exception when saving a subclass object

Tags: c#, nhibernate

My database contains three tables ‘Person’ , ‘LegalPerson’ and  ‘RealPerson’.
in my code ‘LegalPerson’ and ‘RealPerson’ classes are driven from ‘Peron’ class
 the Entity Relationship diagram between these three entities is as following picture:
[image]

i use SubClassMap  for both 'RealPerson' and 'LegalPerson' mappings.
the problem is when i try to save for example a 'LegalPerson' object with Person_Id that is already saved in 'Person' table, i get the following exception:
An unhandled exception of type 'NHibernate.StaleObjectStateException' occurred in NHibernate.dll

Additional information: Row was updated or deleted by another transaction (or unsaved-value mapping was incorrect)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem.
Saving any object of type 'RealPerson' or 'LegalPerson' will save an entry implicitly in 'Person' table as well as in 'RealPerson' or 'LegalPerson'.